# TouchXml installation on xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, xcode6, libxml2, xcode6.1, touchxml

I try to get TouchXml to work on Xcode 6.1 .

I have problem with the libxml2.dylib configuration, i get "libxml/tree.h file not found".
how can i solve this problem?